# Changing nav-bar links according to whether a user has created a profile or not (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, model, devise

I'm making a rails app and have created a simple navbar that works fine. I have set up devise and created a profile model which I would like users to create after they sign up, and (I believe) I have correctly made the necessary associations.

As a new user signs in for the first time, I would like a "Create profile" link to show in the nav-bar using the new_profile_path, but once that specific user has created his/her profile, i would like the "create Profile" to change to "View Profile" and remain that way permanently, which should redirect to the profile_path.

The code I currently have in my nav-bar is the following:

```
<ul>
         <li><%= link_to root_path do %>
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>Main
            <% end %>
        </li>
        <% if current_user.profile %>
         <li><%= link_to profile_path(current_user.profile) do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>Employee Profile<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
            <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "New Profile", new_profile_path %></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><%= link_to "Tasks / Activities", tasks_path %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Vacations", vacations_path %></li>
                </ul>
         </li>
         <li><%= link_to projects_path do %>
                <i class="fa fa-building-o"></i>Projects<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
                <% end %>
            <ul>
```

However even after creating the new profile the link "Create Profile" still remains. How can I fix this?

Comment: how you are redirecting after_sign_up_path to new_profile_path?

Comment: Besides de User and Profile models, also add the result from the command line for the code User.find(ID).profile

Comment: @rashed Very first, please correct your code, as it contains some miss-match for `<% end %>` and `</li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% if !current_user.profile.blank? %>
  <%= link_to profile_path(current_user.profile) do %>
         <i class="fa fa-user"></i>Employee Profile<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
      <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "New Profile", new_profile_path %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried implementing the code you provided, however I am now getting a new error:

NoMethodError in Pages#main

undefined method `exists?' for nil:NilClass


Any ideas how to correct this issue?

Comment: ok, the new code seems to correct the error, however I am still facing the same initial problem which is that the New Profile link doesnt change even if i make a profile and submit it, it still remains there. I am wondering if there may be an issue with regards to the profile being saved and linked to the user. could this be the case? if so do you have any suggestions on how to fix it? (sorry this is my first time making a rails app so excuse my ignorance)

Comment: Update your question with necessary code so that i can debug it.

Comment: Nevermind I figured out the problem. It turns out that when i was submitting the profile information, it wasnt being linked to that particular user. Anyway thanks for fixing the problem with my navbar links, the code you provided did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here `<% end %><% else %>`. You close the `if` test before your `else`. Result: `<%= link_to "New Profile", new_profile_path %>` is always displayed!

Remove the 10th line and it'll work fine.